# Sending HTML values in Contact Form 7 (CF7)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

Currently I have a page with a few JS buttons and a CF7 contact form beneath the buttons

I have a field on this page that shows a value set by the buttons `<input type="number" id="price"/>`

I was wondering if there is a simple way to send the price value in the CF7 email using something like `document.getElementById('price').value`

Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create hidden field for price in cf7:

```
// hidden was css class for hidding field, id is your input price id for cf7
[number price class:hidden  id:price_to_send]
```

then added value from your input price outside cf7 into the hidden field

```
$('#price').change(function() {
    $('#price_to_send').val($(this).val());
});
```

**note:** If you needed to validate input before sending, you can using wpcf7_before_send_mail  action, or other action / filter:  http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.7/

Comment: It still doesn't process HTML when the field is used in the email body.

Answer (score 0):

Field in form `<input type="number" name="price">`

Shortcode in Email template `[price]`

Sending HTML Value from field to email template:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'change_my_data', 10, 1 );
function change_my_data($instance) {
    if( $instance->id() == "266" ) {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ( $submission ) {
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
            $properties = $instance->get_properties();
            $body = $properties['mail']['body'];
            $body = str_replace('[price]', html_entity_decode($posted_data['price']), $body);
            $properties['mail']['body'] = $body;
            $instance->set_properties($properties);
        }
    }
    return $instance;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).